# scroll a table horizontally and vertically on webpage

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i have a table on a webpage. I want to scroll it vertically as well as horizontally. But its not working for me . 
I tried using actions but that also didnot help. Below is the action code what i used

```
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.id(ID));
Actions builder = new Actions (driver);
builder.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build().perform();
```

Also i tried :

```
int height = slider.getSize().getHeight();
int width = slider.getSize().getWidth();
dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(height,0).release().build();
```

Strangely what ever value i assign the slidder moves only by 6 rows.

HTML of the tale:

```
    <div id="pt1:pc1:md1::scroller" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; z-index: 0; width: 770px; top: 46px; height: 187px; right: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 1260px; height: 6562px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe some solution based on JS would be helpful? I don't have any exact sample, however this seems to work for normal scrolling of page, so maybe after some tuning it could fit your question as well:
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scroll(0, 150);");

Answer (score 0):

for these kinda of "bottlenecks" (as Arek described in the comment to question) try js approach.
for my selenium automation project I wrote a set of methods (that use jsExecutor). Think the idea below should help you (methods code provided):

```
public void jsClick(Strning cssSelector) {
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}

public String jsGetText(String cssSelector){
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssSelector+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());

return res;
}

public String jsGetColor(String css){

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+css+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.css('color')");
        String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
        return res;

    }
```

Hope this somehow helps you.